# Proving the u-substitution formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

Let $g: [a, b] \rightarrow [c,d] $ be continuously differentiable and $f: [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous. Prove that

$\int_{a}^{b} f(g(x))g'(x) dx $ = $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $

What I have so far:

$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $ = $ F(g(b)) - F(g(a)) $

So after a bit of figuring, I've realized that

$\int_{a}^{b} f(g(x))g'(x) dx $  contains the formula of the chain rule inside of it, which is essentially arrived at by taking the derivative of the composition of the differential functions f and g. So, integrating it would result in the antiderivative of $ F(g(b)) - F(g(a)) $, which is equivalent to the antiderivative of $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $ .  Thus,

$ \therefore \int_{a}^{b} f(g(x))g'(x) dx $ = $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $

Comment: What you have is correct. What is the antiderivative of $f(g(x))g'(x)$?

Comment: Would it be $F(g(b))g'(b) - F(g(a))g'(a)?$

Comment: No. Think chain rule.

Comment: Oh okay, integrating this expression would be like undoing the chain rule, correct? So, would I get $F(g(b)) - F(g(a))$?

Comment: Which, this antiderivative should be equivalent to the antiderivative I get when I solve $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $?

Comment: Right. The antiderivatives themself aren't equivalent; in general $F(g(x)) \neq F(x)$ but when you take into account the bounds the integrals are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi(t) = \int_a^t f(g(x))g'(x)dx - \int_{g(a)}^{g(t)} f(\tau) d \tau$.

Note that $\phi(a) = 0$ and from the Leibniz rule we have $\phi'(t) = 0$ for $t \in [a,b]$. Hence $\phi(t) = 0$ for $t \in [a,b]$ and so $\phi(b) = 0$.

Comment: Most beautiful proof I've seen of this

Answer (score 2):

Put $\psi(x):=F\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$. Then
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(t)\>dt=F\bigl(g(b)\bigr)-F\bigl(g(a)\bigr)=\psi(b)-\psi(a)=\int_a^b \psi'(x)\>dx=\int_a^bf\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\>g'(x)\>dx\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Let $t = g(x)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Would  $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt $ become $\int_{a}^{b} f(g(x))dx $?